# angular.json file not found error when building angular project via ng build

Tags: angular, npm

I clone a repository on my laptop which I had created this source one month ago from another computer. My project was successful and that didn't have any kind of error one month ago. but today after I cloned the repository in new computer i faced with some errors.
Actually I wrote `npm i` for installing packages then i tried to build my project via `ng build`

but these error happend:

> Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found. Error: Local
>   workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.

someone suggest me to delete `npm` and `npm-cache` from `AppData\Roaming` and  delete `package-lock.json` from the `src` directory, then install package again. but this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the project's root folder structure?

Comment: Hi! First of all, in which directory is `angular.json` file located? Usually, it should be directly inside "ClientApp", is it located there or in other sub-folders/upper-folders? Is it named `angular-cli.json` or `angular.json` (they are actually the same, but from angular v6+ angular-cli.json became angular.json. If it's still named angular-cli.json and you are using angular v6+, then something went wrong during update)? And,... What version of Angular and Angular-Cli are you using (i mean, the one written in package.json)?

Comment: Try `ng update @angular/cli --save` this will create an angular.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Supposed your project is use an old version of angular cli (this use the `angular-cli.json` file) and on your computer is a newer version that require the `angular.json` instead.

In order to archieve this you should run **ng update @angular/cli**. Somethimes it require to run this twice. Then you should have an updated project.

[The official documentation for updates](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/update) allow the flag `migrate-only`. This can be usefull if you only want to archieve a migration and not a complete update. then run: 
`ng update @angular/cli --from=x.x.x --migrate-only` where `x.x.x` represents your actual version of cli.