# Angular 5.2 Local workspace file angular.json not found

Tags: angular, docker

Im trying to spin up an angular project in a docker, but I am encountering the following error:

```
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
    at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (C:\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:44:19)
    at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (C:\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:31:21)
    at ServeCommand._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect (C:\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:201:32)
    at ServeCommand.<anonymous> (C:\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:53:25)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:3:12)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:52:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:127:23)
```

I am able to run the project on my local computer, and the angular.json file does exist in the root folder of the project.

**Output from ng -v:**

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.2
Node: 10.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/core              0.5.13
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.5.13
@angular/cdk                      5.2.5
@angular/cli                      6.2.2
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.5
@schematics/angular               0.8.2
@schematics/update                0.8.2
rxjs                              5.5.12
typescript                        2.4.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

I have found one question on stackoverflow referring to this issue, but the solutions found there is to update angular from version 1.7, which we are not running in this project. I also tried updating the project to run angular 6 instead of 5, with the same outcome.

**UPDATE:**

Even if I run `ng update @angular/core` to get core up to version 6, I'm still getting the same error. Contents of my project folder:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM                .vs
d-----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM                e2e
d-----        9/20/2018  10:28 AM                git
d-----        9/20/2018  10:29 AM                nodejs
d-----        9/20/2018  10:29 AM                node_modules
d-----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM                src
d-----        9/20/2018  10:28 AM                yarn
-a----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM           1631 .angular-cli.json
-a----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM            258 .editorconfig
-a----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM            587 .gitignore
-a----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM           4737 angular.json
-a----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM            993 karma.conf.js
-a----       11/20/2016  12:32 PM           1894 License.txt
-a----        9/18/2018   3:05 PM           1241 ng-add-pug-loader.js
-a----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM             60 ngxi18n.bat
-a----        9/18/2018   3:40 PM         432758 package-lock.json
-a----        9/18/2018   2:41 PM           2234 package.json
-a----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM            750 protractor.conf.js
-a----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM           1061 README.md
-a----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM             28 run.bat
-a----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM            450 tsconfig.json
-a----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM           3180 tslint.json
-a----        9/18/2018   1:20 PM            338 wathappand.txt
```

Comment: angular.json is only in angular 6 not in 5

Comment: @harkeshkumar If thats the case, I have no idea why its complaining about it, or how its even there. I have CLI v 6.2 and Core v 5.2

Answer (score 0):

For a angular 6 app you need a `angular.json` instead of `angular-cli.json` for old `angular cli` version. You can take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52404758/6432698 to see how you can upgrade your project settings.

Comment: If you read the question, you'll see that I already have the angular.json file in my project. I am running Angular CLI 6.2 and Angular Core 5.2

Comment: Your docker container try to read old projects settings. You need to look at your settings in the docker container. I would be careful when it comes to two different versions of the core and cli.

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on that. How can the Docker Container read old settings, when its a fresh install, and its pulling the latest version of the project from our GIT? If I do this on my computer, it works.

Comment: if you replaced your `angular-cli.json` e.g manually in your local configuration. docker can not know anything about it. At the point you have to teach that you are in an angular cli 6+ version.

Answer (score 0):

Angular CLI 6 searchs for a `angular.json` while Angular CLI 5 searches for a `angular-cli.json` file in your workspace.

You may have to install an old version of Angular CLI and use it to launch your project. Look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50467119/1743633) and change versions according to the desired CLI version.

Comment: On my local computer, Im running Angular CLI 6.1.5. If I try to downgrade the CLI in the docker to this version as well, I'm still getting the same error.